# Append after 'this is an example' a new line and a String using sed in macOS

Tags: bash, sed, macos-sierra

I tried so many but it doesn't seem to work on macOS Terminal. My file contains the String `this is an example` zero to multiple times. After this the script should insert a new line followed by another String, for example `this is an inserted line` and safe it back to the original file (in concrete case the sudoers file should be modified).

I didn't got the participle of the syntax of `sed` on macOS, so I would be pleasured if I get a functional script with an understandable explanation. Thanks! :)

**EDIT**

Here's one sample command, the script should find `%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL` from the sudoers file, then insert a new line and the current account.

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers | sed 'a/\%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL\
testaccount  ALL=(ALL) ALL' > test.txt
```

Comment: Show us what you tried with `sed` and perhaps we'll be able to see where things went wrong.  Also, in general a sample input and output file are very helpful for people trying to tell if they have the right solution for you or not

Comment: @EricRenouf Done. And to sample input: It's sudoers file.

Comment: @EricRenouf It is no duplicate, because the script from this question created here an error `sed '/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/a CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file
sed: 1: "/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/a C ...": command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: That answer is for GNU sed, if you look at the next answer down it provides one that works with BSD sed as well, which should work on the Mac I expect